# Visual Studio plugin that shows who checked in code

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

I have vague memory of a screenshot of a VS plugin that colors different code sections, based on who gave them the last modification.
Anyone knows what I'm talking about?

(I'm doing native c++ / MS Team source control. I can only hope this tool, if at all exists, supports this configuration)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using TFS or any source control that integrates with Visual Studio's source control provider model, just right click inside a file, go to "Source Control" and select "Annotate".

Comment: Dan - Thanks! 
I just realized why I couldn't find this feature - TFS does not support this natively. it is currently part of its power tools: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=7324C3DB-658D-441B-8522-689C557D0A79&displaylang=en

Comment: Interesting, I had thought that this was built in. I am using VS2008 and I do already have the power tools installed, so its possible its part of the power tools.